# I get a 404 error when using formsubmit.co on github pages

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-5, github-pages

I am building a website using Bootstrap 5 and I created a form that I want to be filled out and sent to my email. I am using [formsubmit.co](https://formsubmit.co) to do this but when I submit the form instead of being taken to the thank you page I created I get a GitHub 404 error and the message isn't sent to my email.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--divinectorweb.com-->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Submit Ticket | </title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/contact.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-project/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/ticket-form.css">
</head>
<body>
    
  <!-- TICKET RQUEST FORM START -->
  <div class="container mt-5 mb-5" id="container-background">
    <h1 class="mb-4">Submit A Ticket</h1>
    <form action="https://formsubmit.co/el/kenigo" method="POST">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Name" class="form-label">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Full Name" name="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Email" class="form-label">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email Address" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Number" class="form-label">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone Number" maxlength="12" name="tel" aria-describedby="emailHelp" id="tel" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Message" class="form-label">Type of Work</label>
            <select class="form-select select-control" data-width="auto" aria-placeholder="" name="type of work" required>
                <option selected>Select A Category</option>
                <option class="select-control" name="type of work" value="CCTV / Alarm Systems">CCTV / Alarm Systems</option>
                <option class="select-control" name="type of work" value="Desktop/Laptop">Desktop/Laptop</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="Fiber Cabling">Fiber Cabling</option>
                <option class="select-control" name="type of work" value="General Tasks">General Tasks</option>
                <option class="select-control" name="type of work" value="Kiosk">Kiosk</option>
                <option class="select-control" name="type of work" value="Low Voltage Cabling">Low Voltage Cabling</option>
                <option class="select-control" name="type of work" value="Networking">Networking</option>
                <option class="select-control" name="type of work" value="Point of Sale (POS)">Point of Sale (POS)</option>
                <option class="select-control" name="type of work" value="Printer">Printer</option>
                <option class="select-control" name="type of work" value="Pro A/V, Digital Signage">Pro A/V, Digital Signage</option>
                <option class="select-control" name="type of work" value="Project management">Project management</option>
                <option class="select-control" name="type of work" value="Server Hardware/Software">Server Hardware/Software</option>
                <option class="select-control" name="type of work" value="Software Development">Software Development</option>
                <option class="select-control" name="type of work" value="Structured Cabling">Structured Cabling</option>
                <option class="select-control" name="type of work" value="Telecom / VOIP">Telecom / VOIP</option>
                <option class="select-control" name="type of work" value="Other">Other</option>
              </select>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Message" class="form-label">Description of the Problem</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Describe the problem clearly. (What is the problem, when the problem started, where did the problem begin, etc. )" name="problem description" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Message" class="form-label">Required Materials/Equipment</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="What equipment or materials are required to resolve the issue?" name="needed materials/equipment" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://patriotsforlife.github.io/Bootstrap-project/thank-you.html">
        <!-- <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false"> -->
        <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="New Ticket Request Submission!">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <script>
            var tele = document.querySelector('#tel');

tele.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  if (event.key != 'Backspace' && (tele.value.length === 3 || tele.value.length === 7)){
  tele.value += '-';
  }
});
        </script>
  </div>
  <!-- TICKET RQUEST FORM CLOSE -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you define the "thank you" page here

```html
 <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://patriotsforlife.github.io/Bootstrap-project/thank-you.html">
```

But when I navigate to that URL: https://patriotsforlife.github.io/Bootstrap-project/thank-you.html

I get a 404 error.  Are you sure you've set this page up correctly?

Given the URL you have, that means your Github repo should be here: https://github.com/patriotsforlife/Bootstrap-project but that's also a 404, meaning the repo does not exist.

Comment: yea that's the wrong link but when I put the correct link I still get a 404 page

Comment: So you're saying that it's redirecting you to an entirely different link than what you specified in the code?